# toom-cook part-3 resolution polinomial

Tags: algorithm, multiplication

Today, I come to ask for your help on a small mathematical problem.
I present a program which calculates an equation with numbers of arbitrary length. https://bitbucket.org/Dermenslof/bistro
in an optimization worries I'm integrating a multiplication algorithm for an operation with two operands exceed 10,000 digits.
this algorithm is toom-cook part-3.
 
Here are principle:
 
we want to do the following operation: 123 456 789 * 987 654 321
 
we will divide these two numbers in three parts:

```
-------------------           ------------------
| 123 | 456 | 789 |           | x2  | x1  | x0 |
-------------------     =     ------------------
| 987 | 654 | 321 |           | y2  | y1  | y0 |
-------------------           ------------------
```

we are told that:

```
the result P(X) = A(X) * B(X)

A(X) = x2 * X² + x1 * X + x0
B(X) = y2 * X² + y1 * X + y0

P(X) = p4 * X⁴ + p3 * X³ + p2 * X² + p1 * X¹ + p0
```

From this one we can obtain:

```
X = -2   A = 369      B = 2961      A * B = AB(2)   = 1092609      = (4 * x2 + 2 * x1 + x0) * (4 * y2 + 2 * y1 + y0)
X = -1   A = 456      B = 654       A * B = AB(-1)  = 298224       = (x2 - x1 + x0) * (y2 - y1 + y0)
X = 0    A = 789      B = 321       A * B = AB(0)   = 253269       = x0 * y0 (gives us directly p0)
X = 1    A = 1368     B = 1962      A * B = AB(1)   = 2684016      = (x2 + 2 * x1 + x0) * (y2 + 2 * y2 + y0)
X = 2    A = 2193     B = 5577      A * B = AB(2)   = 12230361     = (4 * x2 + 2 * x1 + x0) * (4 * y2 + 2 * y1 + y0)
X = inf  A = 123      B = 987       B * B = AB(inf) = 121401       = x2 * y2 (gives us directly p4)
```

we infer this:

```
AB(-2) = 16 * p4 - 8 * p3 + 4 * p2 + 2 * p1 + p0
AB(-1) = p4 - p3 + p2 - p1 + p0
AB(0)  = p0
AB(1)  = p4 + p3 + p2 + p1 + p0
AB(2)  = 16 * p4 + 8 * p3 + 4 * p2 + 2 * p1 + p0
```

we must now isolate p3, p2 and p1

```
p3 = (2 * AB(-1) + AB(2) - 18p4 - 6p2 - 3p0) / 6
p2 = (AB(1-) + AB(1) - 2 * p4 - 2 * p0) / 2
p1 = AB(-1) - p4 - p3 - p2 - p0
```

My result is:

```
  121 401 000 000 000 000
+ 000 530 514 000 000 000
+ 000 001 116 450 000 000
+ 000 000 000 662 382 000
+ 000 000 000 000 253 269
-------------------------
  121 932 631 112 635 269
```

everything works.
now there is something that trouble me is this:

```
p3 = (2 * AB(-1) + AB(2) - 18 * p4 - 6 * p2 - 3 * p0) / 6
```

for technical reasons it is found that the divisions are horribly slow to calculate. divide by 2 or by a power of the base is not a problem.
but divide a potentially very large numbers by 6 is a huge one.
 
so you have to find different values of X, or another form of this polynomial for a more appropriate equation.

I got a little information and apparently the following equations are more appropriate:
(https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/source/src-9.0/third/gmp/doc/multiplication)

```
AB(0)            = p0
16 * AB(1/2)     = p4 + 2 * p3 + 4 * p2 + 8 * p1 + 16 * p0
AB(1)            = p4 + p3 + p2 + p1 + p0
AB(2)            = 16 * p4 + 8 * p3 + 4 * p2 + 2 * p1 + p0
AB(inf)          = p4
```

and this is where I ask your help, I can not from these equation to isolate p3, p2 and p1
 
thank you in advance to those who interesserons this problem

Comment: up please, i take all usable information

Answer (score 0):

`I cannot from these [equations isolate] p3, p2 and p1`
I started to *edit your question* to fix the odd sign error (not the only one; see *AB(-2)*), went on to align "*p*s" (finding the result very similar to a table close to the one in the old GMP doc you linked):

```
  AB(0)   =                            p0
16AB(1/2) =   p4 + 2p3 + 4p2 + 8p1 + 16p0
  AB(1)   =   p4 +  p3 +  p2 +  p1 +   p0
  AB(2)   = 16p4 + 8p3 + 4p2 + 2p1 +   p0
  AB(inf) =   p4
```

"Obviously, we can" subtract appropriate multiples of the first and last line to get

```
h = 2p3 + 4p2 + 8p1
u =  p3 +  p2 +  p1
d = 8p3 + 4p2 + 2p1
```

similarly, `10u -h-d gives` `6p2`, `2h-12u+ d` `6p1`, and symmetrically `h-12u+2d` `6p3`.
This still needs at least one divide by 6 (or three, if you consider /2 "free") - which, for all I can gather, is [state of the art](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/generic/toom_interpolate_5pts.c) as of late '17.

Comment: The real question is does a Toom3 variant exist that has an interpolation with only bit shifts and without division by non powers of 2.  From what I see Toom4 can be done this way but Toom3 maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

"for technical reasons it is found that the divisions are horribly slow to calculate"

I know this will likely not help you or most people looking for an answer to this problem, but SOME divisions, in particular divisions by q=2^k +1 or q=2^k -1 (for small k) and their composites can be computed very efficiently IN HARDWARE, with a circuit complexity comparable to a carry lookahead or similar fast adder.

Without getting too bogged down in the details, it is possible to divide the integer in blocks of 2^K or 2^(K+1) bits, compute the remainders of each block modulo q in parallel, and then use a prefix sum modulo q to find the partial remainders at each stage of the division, from which the result n= floor(a/q) and remainder r can be obtained.

Another way to see it is as a generalization of the well known divisibility test algorithms in base 10, which rely on the fact that:

```
10^n = 1 mod 3 
10^n = 1 mod 9
```

In any case I am not aware of any commercial cpu that efficiently implements this operation, and the fastest known alternatives in software are multiplying by, say, 1/3 = 0x55555555... or do the same with shifts and additions, which in modern cpus is almost certain to be slower:

```
a*0x55555... = a*0x5*0x11111... = ... = 
a*0x5*0x11*0x101*0x10001...
```

which can be implemented in C as:

```
a = a + (a<<2);
a = a + (a<<4);
a = a + (a<<8);
a = a + (a<<16);
...
```